# I'm trying to convert a normal Markdown document to a PDF using pandoc. I'm getting LaTeX errors

Tags: conversion, latex, markdown, pandoc, pdflatex

Here is the entire markdown:

```
---
title: Calculus hw
author: Jewel
date: April 21, 2023
---

> Question 1

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
Asin(x)+Bcos(x) & \text{if } x < 0 \\
x^2+1 & \text{if } x \geqslant 0
\end{cases}
$$

For $f(x)$ to be continuous at $x=0$ ,
$RHL = LHL = f(0)$

$RHL = \lim_{x \to 0} (x^2+1)\ = 1$
$LHL = \lim_{x \to 0} (Asin(x)+Bcos(x))\ = B$
$f(0)=1 \implies B =1$

for $f$ to be differentiable at 0 :  
RHD = LHD

##### RHD at $x=0$

$\lim_{h \to 0} {\dfrac{(0+h)^2 + 1 - 0^2-1}{h}} = 0$

<!-- ##### LHD at $x=0$ : -->
$= \lim_{h \to 0} { \dfrac{Asin(0+h)+Bcos(0+h)-Asin(0)-Bcos(0)}{h}}$

$= \lim_{h \to 0} { \dfrac{Asin(h)+Bcos(h)-B}{h}}$

$= \lim_{h \to 0} { \dfrac{Asin(0+h)+Bcos(0+h)-Asin(0)-Bcos(0)}{h}}$

$= A+ B\lim_{h \to 0} { \dfrac{cos(h)-1}{h}}$

Applying L'Hopital as it is a $\dfrac{0}{0}$ case

$ = A+ \lim_{h \to 0}{-sin(h)} = A+0 = A$

so for RHD = LHD , $A=0$

 $(A,B)=(0,1)$

---  

> Question 2

Let $f(t)$ denote distance (in km) travelled in time $t$ ( in minutes) .
$ f(0)=0, f(5) = 5$ *( in question )*

$f$ is continuous , differentiable in $[0,5]$ assuming smooth motion of car

So by Mean-Value Thereom , $ \exists$ $c$ $\in [0,5] $ such that :
$$ f'(c) = \dfrac{f(5)-f(0)}{5-0} = 1 km/min = 60km/hr$$
so at some  $c \in (0,5)$ , Alice's speed $> 58km/hr$ . So she will be fined.

---

> Question 3

$f : (0,\frac{\pi}{2}) \to \mathbb{R} $.
$f(x) = sin(x)^\pi-\pi sin(x) +\pi $
I = $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$

$f(x)$ is continuous , diffrentiable in I by algebra of continuous and differentiable functions

$f'(c) = \pi sin(c)^ {(\pi-1)} cos(c) - \pi cos(c) \leqslant 0$

Take $m,n \in I , n>m$

$ f$ is diffrentiable , continuous in [m,n] :

By Mean-Value thereom , there $ \exists c \in [m,n]$ st :

$f'(c) = \frac{f(n)-f(m)}{n-m} \leq 0 \implies f(n)< f(m)$

so $f$ is decreasing in I as we chose **any** two points in I

$f(0) = \pi , f(\frac{\pi}{2}) = 1 $
as $f$ is decreasing , its minimum value in I is 1 .
So $f > 0 $ in I
```

Here is the error message

```
PS C:\Users\jewel> cd .\OneDrive\Desktop\
PS C:\Users\jewel\OneDrive\Desktop> pandoc nmims.md -o xyz.pdf
Error producing PDF.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.95 \$ = A+ \lim
```

This is my first time using markdown. I tried researching the error online, but didn't find any useful solutions.

Comment: Can you try to trim down the input document to _just_ the part which produces the error, and explain what you hoped the output to be?

Comment: The error is at line `\$ = A+ \lim` and the difference looks to be space after `$`. It also looks like LaTeX error with quick look at Google, not Markdown, because why would Markdown care? Not sure why pandoc throws a LateX error if you're indeed using the shown command, though.

Comment: Ok, I see what happens, it detects LaTeX automatically and goes for conversion with  `pdflatex` . Do you want that to happen or do you want to just convert those parts to text?

Comment: @Destroy666 i just wanted it to render like normal latex would

Comment: update - i changed as per @tripleee 's suggestion, but now i have another error 

```PS C:\Users\jewel\OneDrive\Desktop> pandoc nmims.md -o xyz.pdf
Error producing PDF.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.113 ...n-Value Thereom , \(\exists\) \(c\) \$\in
```

Comment: So... use correct LaTeX in that case? There are many mistakes except the one I listed indeed, without even knowing LaTeX. This question is much more suitable here https://tex.stackexchange.com/ as long as these mistakes aren't very basic ones, in which case you should just correct them yourself. Errors clearly state the mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely issue is that there are spaces around some delimiting `$` characters. Pandoc's manual, under the [*Pandoc's Markdown > Math* section](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#math), explains it:

> Anything between two `$` characters will be treated as TeX math. The opening `$` must have a non-space character immediately to its right, while the closing `$` must have a non-space character immediately to its left, and must not be followed immediately by a digit. Thus, `$20,000 and $30,000` won’t parse as math.

So `$ f(0)=0, f(5) = 5$` should be `$f(0)=0, f(5) = 5$` and `$f > 0 $` should become `$f > 0$`, etc.